# Image search returns no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-search-api

My Mac recently "retired" so I successfully ported my Rails 2.3.8 app to an Ubuntu installation on Windows.  Everything works well except now I don't get any results when I do an image search using my Google custom search (CSE).

I have a valid API key and a unique custom search ID - this is confirmed because I get results when executing a regular "web" search using the CSE.  I am also well within the daily request limit.  I've also double-checked the API reference to ensure that the published syntax hasn't changed and it hasn't.

I am issuing the following requests:

```
result_count=10
query='apple'
```

**1) Web Search (yields results) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

```
type=''
url="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_KEY']}&cx=#{ENV['GOOGLE_SEARCH_ID']}#{type}&alt=json&num=#{result_count}&q=#{query}"
```

RESULT =>  As expected, a JSON-format string with 10 items/results

**2) Image Search (NO results regardless of query) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

```
type='&searchType=image'
url="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_KEY']}&cx=#{ENV['GOOGLE_SEARCH_ID']}#{type}&alt=json&num=#{result_count}&q=#{query}"
```

RESULT =>  A JSON-format string with 0 items/results, shown below:

```
{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
 "queries": {
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - apple",
    "totalResults": "0",
    "searchTerms": "apple",
    "count": 10,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "my_private_cx_id",
    "searchType": "image"
   }
  ]
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.023136,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.02",
  "totalResults": "0",
  "formattedTotalResults": "0"
 }
}
```

The image search used to work until I ported the app - I don't know what I'm missing but I suspect it is a minor oversight.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may due to that you haven't enabled image search for your customized search engine. You can enable that under the console of the CSE

Comment: Good Stuff.  Thank you Redan - I missed that somehow.  All working now.  Cheers.